# Prove that $(x-a,y-b)$ is a maximal ideal of $K[x,y]$ (without algebraic geometry)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Have to prove that $(x-a, y-b)$ is a maximal ideal of $K[x,y]$ .
I looked for a proof but it involved algebraic geometry. 
I don't know algebraic geometry. 
I have seen one proof in math stacks exchange ,in which the quotient ring is shown to be Field. I am posting this question for more elementary proof (easy proof ) ,if there is one.

Comment: What is K[X,Y] ?

Comment: You could compute the quotient, and see that it is a field.

Comment: Hint: Consider the map that evaluates a polynomial at $(a,b)$.

Comment: For the converse (that maximal ideals are of this form) one usually uses algebraic geometry, e.g., Hilbert's Nullstellensatz - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545506/hilberts-nullstellensatz-and-maximal-ideals).  However, your question is elementary.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe that you saw a proof using algebraic geometry. This is very simple (that follows from that fact that it's algebra but I see how to do it).

It's enough to show that $$(x-a,y-b)=\{p\in K[x,y]:p(a,b)=0\}.$$

For the less obvious of the two inclusions, assume that $p(a,b)=0$. Now $x^n=((x-a)+a)^n=\dots$ and similarly for $y^n$, so there exists a polynomial $P$ with $$p(x,y)=P(x-a,y-b).$$So $P(0,0)=p(a,b)=0$. So $P$ has vanishing constant term. Every other term is divisible by $x$ or by $y$, so there exist $Q$ and $R$ with $$P(x,y)=xQ(x)+yR(y).$$So $$p(x,y)=(x-a)Q(x-a)+(y-b)R(y-b),$$hence $p\in(x-a,y-b)$.

Comment: you are saying that xb-ya belongs to the ideal because we can write x as x-a+a,and similar for y.
Am I correctly getting your logic?

Comment: C.Ullrich does (x-a,y-b) mean polynomials whose terms are product of (x-a) and (x-b)? please give me the general form of an element in K[X,Y].

Comment: @lowiq Oh dear. If you don't know the _definition_ of $K[x-a,y-b]$ then asking how to prove things about it is premature. The definition is in the book...

Comment: as far as I understand, the polynomial ring in two variables can be obtained as:K[x,y]=k[x][y] .I asked for example of a polynomial that belongs to the ideal (x-a, y-b) so that I can understand solution clearly.

Comment: @lowiq Right. The $K[x-a,y-b]$ in my last comment was a typo for $(x-a,y-b)$, sorry.

Comment: there is one proof of this question  using some isomorphism theorem on this wetsite.i know we can prove it by showing that the quotient by ideal is a field.can you tell me what more result is needed to prove  it this way?

Answer (score 1):

This one is very elementary, using only the definition of maximal: After applying some automorphism, it suffices to deal with $I=(x,y)$. Take some $f \notin I$. Then $f$ has non-zero constant coefficient, i.e. $f=xg+yh+c$ for some non-zero constant $c$. We deduce:

$$c = f - xg -yh \in (I,f),$$

i.e. $(I,f)=(1)$. Thus we have shown $I$ is maximal, since we have shown that any larger ideal is the whole ring.

Comment: what does (I, f) mean?

Comment: The ideal generated by $I$ and $f$, you might also find this notated as $I+(f)$.

Comment: C belongs to that ideal. And so it is generated by 1.but how does it prove its maximal? Because 1 generates whole ring?

Comment: since it is field and unit element belongs to ideal ,it generates the whole ring.