# Showing $\langle x,y \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $K[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

The biggest thing that it stopping me from progressing in this question is the fact that I have two elements in the ideal, this topic it still very new to me.

I can show that $I=\langle x \rangle$ and $I=\langle y \rangle$ are prime ideals on their own by showing that $^{K[x,y]}/_I$ is an integral domain through the First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings. How do I proceed with this question now that there are two elements in the ideal?

If I were to attempt it, knowing that $K$ is a field, I would define a homomorphism $\phi:K[x,y]\rightarrow K,f(x,y)\rightarrow f(0,0)$. Clearly $\ker \phi = \langle x \rangle \cup\langle y \rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$. So we have that $^{K[x,y]}/_{\langle x , y \rangle} \cong K$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings, and since $K$ is a field, it is an integral domain, and thus $\langle x , y \rangle$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Yes, $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817376/prove-that-x-a-y-b-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-kx-y-without-algebraic-geometr) and hence a prime ideal.

Comment: Your formula $\langle x \rangle \cup\langle y \rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ is false. For example $x+y\in \langle x,y\rangle$  but  $x+y\notin    \langle x \rangle \cup\langle y \rangle$

Comment: Not sure what is your question. Your proof is correct. Though I'd like to point that the equality $(x,y)=(x)\cup (y)$ is false.

Comment: That's an understanding error on my part, I suppose I was trying to say that the kernel is $\langle x \rangle$ AND $\langle y \rangle$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definiton the ideal $(x,y)$ is the set of polynomials in $K[x,y]$ of the form
$$
xA(x,y)+yB(x,y)
$$
where $A(x,y)$ and $B(x,y)$ are any polynomials. Thus, it is quite clear that a polynomial
$$
a_{0,0}+a_{1,0}x+a_{0,1}y+a_{2,0}x^2+a_{1,1}xy+a_{0,2}y^2+\cdots
$$
is in $(x,y)$ if and only if $a_{0,0}=0$.

Thus one may check directly that $(x,y)$ is a prime ideal by showing that the constant term of a product $P(x,y)Q(x,y)$ is $0$ of and only if one of the constant terms of $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ is zero. This is true because the constant term of a prduct of polynomials is the prduct of the constant terms and $K$ is a field.

(So the result is true also for the ring $R[x,y]$ where $R$ is a domain, although in this case $(x,y)$ is not maximal)

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to factor out by the ideal $(x,y)$. $$\frac{K[x,y]}{(x,y)} \cong \frac{\frac{K[x,y]}{(x)}}{\frac{(x,y)}{(x)}} \cong \frac{K[y]}{(y)} \cong K$$

Comment: This might sound like a very obvious statement, but we can treat quotient groups almost like... regular quotients/fractions?

Comment: It seems that you are not familiar with the third theorem of isomorphism for rings. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_C_(rings)).